# Getting redirect header without trailing slash

Tags: http, curl, server

I am trying to put a REST service on my url.
Now when I use:

```
    curl -i http://api.myservice.com/app
```

I get 'HTTP/1.1 301 MOVED PERMANENTLY'
and Location: http://api.myservice.com/app/

Notice the trailing slash in the "new" location.

When I send a get request using:

```
    curl -i http://api.myservice.com/app/
```

I get the desired response with and HTTP/1.1 200 OK

My question is why does this happen and how can I avoid getting "moved permanently" response without the trailing slash?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
curl -Li http://api.myservice.com/app
```

With that your request well be redirected if a 3xx is received.

Comment: Can you tell me the reason it is redirected and to avoid it happening?

Comment: It depends on the logic behind the server. If you doesn't own the service, you can't don anything (but what I said before). If you own the service, you must change the logic behind.
You can't do anything to change the behaviour from the client side.